# Attempt to assign property of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error with this code

in my MediaController.php:

```
public function editMediaGuide($mediaItem)
{
    //ipv aparte pagina gwn de pagina echo'en (niet zeker of dit mag)
    $media = DB::table('tblMedia')->where('PK_media_id', $mediaItem)->get();

    echo $media->title;
 }
```

in routes.php :

```
Route::get('/guide/dashboard/media/edit/{mediaItem}', array('as' => 'guide-media-edit', 'uses' => 'MediaController@editMediaGuide'));
```

in my view where I click a specific item (this is giving the right PK_media_id)  :

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('guide-media-edit', $media->PK_media_id) }}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the issue problem is with

> echo $media->title;

You are not passing data the view. Try this -

```
$view = View::make('media', $media);
```

Reference - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views